# How do I disable truncating long external command outputs?

Tags: neovim, filter

When I run an external/filter command in neovim,
it "sometimes" truncates the output with three dots: "..."

For example:

```
:! tree /home
```

```
│   │   │   │   │   ├── hi.pak.info
│   │   │   │   │   ├── hr.pak
│   │   │   │   │   ├── hr.pak.info
│   │   │   │   │   ├── hu.pak
│   │   │   ...   <------------- this
<a0> │   │   ├── libavplugin-ffmpeg-57.so
│   │   │   │   ├── libavplugin-ffmpeg-58.so
│   │   │   │   ├── libawt_headless.so
│   │   │   │   ├── libawt.so
```

Another command to trigger this behavior is below.

```
:!python3 -c "print(''.join('1' for _ in range(65536)))"
```

Some others encounter this even with less characters:

```
:!python3 -c "print(''.join('1' for _ in range(10239)))"
```

How do I disable this?
I want to see the whole output of the command I run, even
if it is long.